# Second monitor problem in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors

I just installed 12.04.1 on an HP Pavilion dv6-2106ea.  I have a second monitor plugged in the VGA port which was detected during the install (and used as a duplicate display).  Now the install is complete it is not being detected.

According to System Settings | System | Details | Graphics I have an "Unknown" driver, but System Settings | Hardware | Additional Drivers says I have NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (currently the Recommended release, but the other has the same effect).

This may be a duplicate of the unanswered https://askubuntu.com/questions/132526/unable-to-use-second-monitor

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your graphics card actually an nVidia card?  If so, try updating the nVidia drivers.

Comment: To check graphics card, try "lspci" without the quotation marks in a terminal window and check for yourself the information about your graphics card and add it as an edit to your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar issue on my Ubuntu 12.04 setup. In my case the problem was with the X Windows setup. I had to start **Dash Home** → **NVidia Xserver Settings** → **X Server Display Configuration**.

The second monitor was **Disabled**, so I have to first enable it and the select configuration **TwinView**. You do need administrator privileges to save the new X Configuration to file, but it will give clue whether your problem is with your drivers or X Windows setup.